# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Angular, Angular-ui-router with Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, webpack

I've been having this problem for awhile, but I can't seem to crack it.  I'm using angular 1.5, angular-ui-router 0.2.18 (from bower components) with webpack 1.13.1 and I provided the code on the bottom. I'm getting the error messages with a [Link 1](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=flyHawaii&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DflyHawaii%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js:61:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js:80:137%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js:79:189)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js:79:432%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js:94:288%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js:62:356)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js:94:136)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js:98:165)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js:75:450) that directs me to angular's website saying this error happens when a module fails to load due to some exception and saying to use ngRoute (but I'm not using ngRoute) and on top of that it shows another [Link 2](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=flyHawaii) saying my module is not available.  So I'm not sure if its angular or angular-ui-router causing this.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var bower_dir = __dirname + '/public//bower_components';
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/public/app/',
    entry: {
        app: './app.js',
        vendor: ['angular']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/app',
        filename: 'app.min.js'
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap:  false })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'jquery': bower_dir + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'angular': bower_dir + '/angular/angular.min.js'
        }
    }
};
```

app.js

```
require("../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js");
require("../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js");
require("../bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js");
var ui_router = require("../bower_components/angular-ui-              router/release/angular-ui-router.js");
require("../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js");
var app = angular.module("flyHawaii", [ui_router]);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("landing", {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "../templates/_landing.html",
        controller: "mainCtrl"
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.other("/");
});
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope = "fooBar";
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="flyHawaii">
<head>
    <title>flyhawaii</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ui-view></div>
    <script src="app/app.min.js"></script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***UPDATE***

navbar.html is a template which leads to a component for _landing.html:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>{{message}}</h1>
</div>
```

_landing.html:

```
<navbar></navbar>
```

Comment: Could you post the error too? And where are you injecting $scope in the controller?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have updated the post with more code on where the scope is being injected and the links for the error is on the bottom. 

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=flyHawaii&p1=Error%…20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapp%2Fapp.min.js%3A75%3A450 

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=flyHawaii)